# Could someone please tell me why this is Segfaulting? (Assembly x86 NASM)

Tags: assembly, parameters, x86, segmentation-fault

Could anyone please explain to me why this is segfaulting? If I remove the `mov [eax],ebx` it does not segfault. But I need to save the new value to `[ebp+8]`. what am I doing wrong? How can I save the new subtracted value into that address?

```
     enter 0,0
                mov eax,[ebp+8]
                call print_nl
                call print_int
                cmp edx,99
                je DontUpdate
                jne Update
                        DontUpdate:
                                leave
                                ret

                Update:
                cmp edi, 5
                jz NoScore
                jnz Score


                        NoScore:


                                mov ebx,eax
   sub ebx,1
                                mov eax,[ebp+8]

                                mov [eax],ebx
                        ;       mov [score],eax
                                mov eax,printScore
                                call print_string
                                mov eax,ebx
                                call print_int
                                mov edi,0
                                pusha
                                popa
                                leave
                                ret
```

Comment: Because you don't have a single comment?

Comment: ?, pretty much all i want to know is how to save ebx to the [ebp+8] address. Is my syntax wrong or something?

Comment: Syntax is correct, but the caller is passing a wrong value. Since you dont show enough code one can not say more. But there were tools invented, called `debugger`, which help in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an invalid pointer (NULL or corrupted) from the caller.

```
mov eax,[ebp+8]
```

**UPDATE**

From your comment I assume that you are passing the value instead of the pointer. unless you post the code where you call the function and the declaration of the variable, there is no more one can determine from your provided info.

Comment: ebp+8 is pointing to a value, i just did not copy that code here. This is just a segment of my code, i did not want to paste the few hundred lines of code.

Comment: That may as well be, that it points to `some` value, but that doesn't mean that the value is a valid pointer. And since you say that this is where the SIGSEGV happens, this has to be the problem. You can argue with me, but not with your OS. ;)

Comment: So right now, my [ebp+8] is the value of my global variable [score] lets say in this case score is =5. Could you try and explain why that would not be a valid pointer?  So in my main it would look like, mov eax,[score] then push eax, then a call to the function posted above

Comment: My crystal ball is in the laundry, so I can not look at your code that you didn't provide. Provide an SSCE than we can help you. Dont' post hundred of lines, just the relevant parts including declarations and the call.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your previous comment. Did you check that?

Comment: @user3043234: if ebp+8 has the value 5, which you store in eax, then trying to put ebx into [eax] tries to store something in memory address 5, which obviously will segfault.